# Cakephp session time out issue

Tags: cakephp-2.0, session-timeout

I have done with all the settings about the Session time out.

Core.php

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
                             'defaults' => 'cake',
                             'timeout'  => '180',
                             'cookieTimeout' => '180',
                             'autoRegenerate' => true,
                             'ini' => array(
                                 'session.cookie_secure' => false
                             )
                        ));

Configure::write('Security.level', 'low');
```

But still the user is getting logged out after 24 mins of inactivity. 
Also the cookei expiration time is not updating on every request. I have made some changes in the Cakesession.php

```
public static $requestCountdown = 1;
```

But still no luck. Can anybody focus light on the issue?

Comment: Can you extend your session timeout to 1800 instead of 180??

Comment: How this will help here? As 180 is in minites. and my security level is also Low...